# How do I use forloop in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I have the values that the user enters in input field stored in something called "values"
I have another array returned from the backend called "existing userdetails" which has all the details of the existing user. 
I need to compare the user input with this array .

I need to use a forloop to check this, but I didnt find the right syntax anywhere. Can I use forEach to do this

```
private existinguser(value) {
console.log("user",this.user)
console.log("value",value)
}
```

this.user returns the existing user details and value returns the input values from the current user. 
What is a way to compare these

Comment: it would be great if you provide your json so we can get idea of json structure

Comment: `I need to use a forloop to check this, but I didnt find the right syntax anywhere.` Did you try googling 'javascript for loop' ?

Comment: i googled forloop for angualr. will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but as per comment:

In HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let obj of users">
    {{ obj | json }}
</div>
```

In TS:

As per your recent code try this:

```
this.users.forEach(x => {
  if (x.name == this.value.name) {
    console.log('Found')
  }
  else {
    console.log('Not found')
  }
})
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7lp4q)

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach ,

```
values.forEach(newUser=> {

      existinguserdetail.forEach(exitingUser=> {

   // Do something


          });
    });
```

Comment: private existinguser(value) {
    console.log("user",this.user)
    console.log("value",value)
    this.user.existingNames.forEach((data) => {
      if(data.user.existingNames.category === value.category)
        this.notApplicable= true
      else this.notApplicable=false
    }
    )}     i tried this but an error

Comment: @user-6589801 Provide the sample JSOn data